# How to display 2 images in datatable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, datatable, datatables

I want to display 2 images in a table using Datatable and Laravel 5.7. The images are showing, but the view table is not good.

This is my html for table:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="row">
      <table id="tableData" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
         <thead>
             <tr style="background-color:#3896D6;">
                <th style="vertical-align: middle!important; text-align: center!important; color: white;" colspan="2">Image Data</th>
             </tr>                   
             <tr>
                 <th style="vertical-align: middle!important; text-align: center!important;">Image 1</th>
                 <th style="vertical-align: middle!important; text-align: center!important;">Image 2</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

This how i render the image to the table

```
$('#tableData').DataTable().destroy();
    $('#tableData').dataTable({
        paging: false,
        info : false,
        searching: false,
        ajax : {
            url : 'monitoring/getphoto/'+id,
            method : 'GET',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
            }
        },
        columns : [
            { 
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    if (row.photo_position == 1) {
                        return '<img width=100 height=100 src="'+ row.photo_url +'">';
                    }else{
                        return '';
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    if (row.photo_position == 2) {
                        return '<img width=100 height=100 src="'+ row.photo_url +'">';
                    }else{
                        return '';
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        columnDefs : [
            {
                "targets" : "_all",
                "className": "text-center",
            }
        ]
    });
```

and this is the image showing in table:

[image]

The table view is not so good, so how do i can fix this?

Comment: Two image in a single row?

Comment: not in a single row, but 2 rows in one column

Comment: You are using if condition to check the photo_position

Comment: do you mean something like this : ```return '<tr><td><img width=100 height=100 src="'+ row.photo_url +'"></td><td><img width=100 height=100 src="'+ row.photo_url +'"></td></tr>';```

Answer (score 0):

`<thead>` with `<th>` is only for the heading. In your case for "Image Data".
After that row you need to close the `<thead>` with `</thead>` and start with `<tbody>`.
In `<tbody>` you use `<td>` instead of `<th>`

So your code would look like this:

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
        <table id="tableData" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color:#3896D6;">
                    <th style="vertical-align: middle!important; text-align: center!important; color: white;" colspan="2">Image Data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle!important; text-align: center!important;">Image 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle!important; text-align: center!important;">Image 2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```